# Log changes to a file between two git tags

Tags: git

Is it possible to log changes to a file (xcdatamodel) between two tags?

I would like to enter two tags and check the commits made on a specific file to help debug a database migration issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following syntax of [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) to compare two arbitrary commits:

> ```
> git diff [--options] <commit> <commit> [--] [<path>…​]
> ```
>
> This is to view the changes between two arbitrary .

Those commits can use any kind of [revision notation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions), including simple tag names. So for two tags `tag1` and `tag2`, the command could look like this:

```
git diff tag1 tag2 -- path/to/file
```